# Flot not showing x-axis label

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, flot

I graph data as follows but I can't seem to get the axis labels to show:

```
!function ($) {
      var options = {
        xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    min: start_time,
                    // max: (new Date()).getTime(),
                    tickSize: [4, "hour"],
                    tickLength: 0,
                    axisLabel: 'Day',
                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                    axisLabelPadding: 3
        },
        yaxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Amount',
                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                    axisLabelPadding: 5
                },
      }
      $.plot($("#placeholder"), [open_emails],options);


    }(window.jQuery
```

I have included the following in my views and they are being loaded

```
//= require jquery.flot
//= require jquery.flot.symbol.min
//= require jquery.flot.axislabels
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

How can I get the labels to show?

Comment: Which jquery.flot.axislabels.js are you using? Google gives me a couple options: https://raw.github.com/RuiPereira/flot/axislabels/jquery.flot.axislabels.js or https://raw.github.com/xuanluo/flot-axislabels/master/jquery.flot.axislabels.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hiya **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wuALT/

So all you need is to add this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://raw.github.com/xuanluo/flot-axislabels/master/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
```

and rest code will start identifying the axisLabel.

Read: <s>http://codenachos.com/view/axis-labels-in-flot</s> **was** a known issue http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=42

This will help and see `Day` and `Amount` appearing in the X and Y axis now.

[image]

Comment: Anyone know why this works and including this in the asset pipeline doesn't...?

Comment: Though I note that in your linked example, the axes no longer show! And when I use  said lib on my project, I can only get the y-axis labels to show, no matter what I do for the x-axis!