# x-axis label in Flot

Tags: flot

All I'm trying to do is label my *x*-axis:

```
function doPlot(position) {//Flot
  $.plot("#placeholder", [//data
    {
      data: theta_plot,
      label: "Angle (rad)",
      yaxis: 1,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      data: omega_plot,
      label: "Angular Velocity (rad/sec)",
      yaxis: 2,
      color: "green"
    },
    {
      data: e_plot,
      label: "Energy (J)",
      yaxis: 3,
      color: "blue"
    }
  ],//options
    {
      xaxis: {
        axisLabel: "Time (sec)",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true
      },
      yaxes: [
        { font: { color: "red" } },
        { font: { color: "green" } },
        { font: { color: "blue" } },
        { alignTicksWithAxis: position === "left" ? 1 : null }
      ],
      legend: {
        position: "nw",
        labelBoxBorderColor: null
      }
    }
    );
}
doPlot("left");
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.  This should be a no-brainer.  All I could come up with is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531428/flot-not-showing-x-axis-label), which is two years old.  Do I still need the `jquery.flot.axislabels.js` library even now?

Here is a [current draft](http://pages.suddenlink.net/physics/amp/amp.htm) of the plot in question.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I still need the jquery.flot.axislabels.js library even now?

Yes.

Simple as that, standard Flot has no axis label feature without plugin.

Comment: Support exists in the development 0.9 version: http://www.flotcharts.org/blog/2013/06/27/planning-for-09/.

Comment: Then the next question is: How long until that version is out of development? ^^

Comment: That's a very good question, it seems to have stalled, last commit in May

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use the plugin, you could add the label yourself after the plot is rendered with a bit of jquery:

```
// create label div
var label = $('<div>Four Score and Seven Years Ago</div>'); 
// intial positioning
label.css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': $('.flot-x-axis').width()/2 + $('.flot-x-axis .tickLabel:first').position()['left']/2, 'top': $('.flot-x-axis').height() + 5});
// append to plot
$('#placeholder').append(label); 
// final position adjustment (label won't have width till appended)
label.css('left', label.position()['left'] - label.width() / 2);
```

On your plot the result is:

[image]